# Into another world while waiting in a car

Tags: story-identification

Story written before 2000; my recollection is exceedingly vague, so this is a long shot at best:

I only really remember the beginning with any clarity - one or two children (I think two, probably siblings) are waiting in a car - I believe at the edge of a forest - when they see something going by, a fairy or something like that. For one reason or another they end up following it and ending up involved in either a hidden world or a hidden aspect of this world.

Sadly, that's all I remember at the moment, but I intend on updating the question if/when I summon more fragments to mind.

Comment: While you're summoning fragments,  I suggest looking at A Walk in Wolf Wood by Mary Stewart. 
"When a weeping man in a strange costume passes their picnic spot and disappears into the nearby woods, a brother and sister decide to follow him and soon find themselves involved in the rescue of a werewolf in the 14th century."